# how to change something in a new TimerTask action in android?

Tags: android

i have a problem with the timerTask in android i have a code like this:

```
timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            countInt = countInt + 1;
            textview1.setText(countInt);
        }
    }, 1000);
```

every time the timer task get startet my app crashed, i thing because i'm accessing the textview and it is in a other thread right?

how to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this..

```
 timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                countInt = countInt + 1;
                yourActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
               public void run(){
                  {textview1.setText(String.valueOf(countInt))});
                }
            }
        }, 1000);
```

It crashes because you are messing with something `( textview1.setText(countInt);)` that belongs UI thread which is not allowed...

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you are right, it crashes cause' you are accessing views from not an UI thread. To solve this, you can post a Runnable to UI thread using your activity

```
timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
        countInt = countInt + 1;
        YourActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                textview1.setText(countInt);
            }
        });
    }
}, 1000);
```