# howto change a value in a TimerTask wichout crashing because of a other thread in android?

Tags: android

i posted a question ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10136620/how-to-change-something-in-a-new-timertask-action-in-android/10136688#10136688)) about how to change UI elements in a timer task, this is fine now.

but when i have a code like this:

```
        countInt = 0;
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                countInt = countInt + 1;
            }
        }, 1000);
```

the counterInt var is saved in the activity where also this code is in.

how to change this value without crashing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are two possibilities:

1) Make countInt into an Integer object and synchronize access to it EVERYWHERE you use it:

```
Integer countInt=0;

synchronized(countInt){
    countInt++;
}
```

2) Use the [AtomicInteger](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html), which might even work better, as it does not block any threads. This prevents the UI from locking up.